# problema com verificação de autenticação do Firebase (Number phone)

Tags: java, android, firebase

Olá! Estou tentando construir um registro do firebase com número de telefone. Fiz os procedimentos que encontrei em:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth?hl=pt-br#ativar-o-login-com-nmero-de-telefone-para-o-projeto-do-firebase

mas estou tendo problema.

**mensagem de erro**:

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This app is not
>   authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verifythat the
>   correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console.
>   [ App validation failed ]

O SHA-1 e o package name estão corretos no firebase console e na API Identify Toolkit. talvez o problema esteja no manifest que eu não consegui entender muito bem como se configura...

meu manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="identitytoolkit.api_key"
        android:value="AIzaSyCYvSvfgFPrbTDbbj-AscV53jIK8ZCx0tE"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="identitytoolkit.server_client_id"
        android:value="409706134960-vq0j4i1kucsstamvhs1j4ruohdg10p2r.apps.googleusercontent.com"/>

    <!-- Splash screen -->
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <data
                android:host="gitkit"
                android:scheme="com.googleusercontent.apps.409706134960-vq0j4i1kucsstamvhs1j4ruohdg10p2r" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Fim do Splash Screen -->

    <!-- Main Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <!-- Fim do Main Activity -->
</application>
```

Comment: Você está usando emulador ou celular ? Este tipo de autenticação não funciona no emulador...

Comment: Estou usando no celular